# Nested events not working for window.onload or DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, php, html, ecmascript-6

I've written some components in JavaScript ES6 and they have multiple events, but when I insert another class on the load event for window the class1 window event doesn't load the Class2. I have tried using DOMContentLoaded as well, but I still get the same result. What can I do to make the events nest together in the load event event for window or DOMContentLoaded events? What is the work around for a situation like this, can it be done? Below is my code example and I'm trying to get Class2 to console log out but it won't!

```js
class Accordian {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
    this.build();
  }
  
  build() {
    const self = this;
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      this.el = document.querySelector(this.selector);
      this.dispatch('accordian__load', event, { el: this.el });
    }, true);
  }
  
  on(name, callback) {
    var func = this['on' + name];

    if (!func) this['on' + name] = [callback];
    else func.push(callback);

    return this;
  }

  dispatch(name, event, ...props) {
    var callbacks = this['on' + name];
    if (callbacks)
      callbacks.forEach((callback) => callback.call(this, event, ...props));
  }

}

class Checkbox {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
    this.build();
  }
  
  build() {
    const self = this;
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      this.el = document.querySelector(this.selector);
      this.dispatch('checkbox__load', event, { el: this.el });
    }, true);
  }
  
  on(name, callback) {
    var func = this['on' + name];

    if (!func) this['on' + name] = [callback];
    else func.push(callback);

    return this;
  }
    
  dispatch(name, event, ...props) {
    var callbacks = this['on' + name];
    if (callbacks)
      callbacks.forEach((callback) => callback.call(this, event, ...props));
  }

}

var accordian = new Accordian('#accordian')
var checkbox = new Checkbox('#chk_enable');

accordian.on('accordian__load', function(event, props) {
  console.log('accordian load');
  console.log(props);
  checkbox.on('checkbox__load', function(event, props) {
    console.log('checkbox load');
    console.log(props);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="accordian">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_enable">
</div>
```

Comment: To add multiple events, consider using `window.addEventListener("load", event => { /* function body */})`

Comment: @Iván show me an example please because I tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: In theory it should work the same way as `.onload`. This is the doc with some live examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: @Iván show me an example to answer my question, that's why I've posted this.

Answer (score 1):

`onload` only accepts one function. One way to avoid this is useing `addEventListener`. To do so, change your:

```js
window.onload = function(event) {
  self.dispatch('load', event, {});
}
```

With

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
  self.dispatch("load", event, {});
});
```

Anyway, the Class2 object is being created inside the Class1 "load" event. A `window.onload` won't trigger twice, so your Class2 "load" won't trigger. You can make ir work if the Class2 object is created outside of Class1 "load".

Finally, you're assigning to the `self` variable without `let` or `const` in both `build` methods. That way, you're redefining `self` to always be the last constructed class:

```js
class Class1 {
  constructor() {
    this.build();
  }
  
  build() {
    const self = this;
    window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
      self.dispatch("load", event, {});
    });
  }
  
  on(name, callback) {
    const self = this;
    var callbacks = this['on' + name];

    if (!callbacks) this['on' + name] = [callback];
    else callbacks.push(callback);

    return this;
  }

  dispatch(name, event, ...props) {
      var callbacks = this['on' + name];
      if (callbacks)
        callbacks.forEach((callback) => callback.call(this, event, ...props));
  }

}

class Class2 {
  constructor() {
    this.build();
  }
  
  build() {
    const self = this;
    window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
      self.dispatch("load", event, {});
    });
  }
  
  on(name, callback) {
        const self = this;
        var callbacks = this['on' + name];
    
        if (!callbacks) this['on' + name] = [callback];
        else callbacks.push(callback);
    
        return this;
    }
    
    dispatch(name, event, ...props) {
        var callbacks = this['on' + name];
        if (callbacks)
          callbacks.forEach((callback) => callback.call(this, event, ...props));
    }

}

var myclass1 = new Class1();

myclass1.on('load', function(event) {
  console.log('Class 1');
});

var myclass2 = new Class2();

myclass2.on('load', function(event) {
  console.log('Class 2');
});
```

Comment: But it's not nested, that's what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: If you want it nested, it won't work. While nested, the order of the execution will be: `Register 1` -> `onload(1)` -> `Register 2`. After registering 2, the event `onload` won't trigger again (already triggered with Class1). Why are you using `window.onload` to register those events?

Comment: You can get it to work if you delclare the variables outside the .on('load', function(){}) scope which will fire inside the load function

Comment: check my original code I updated it, is there anyway to improve it

Comment: I don't know your use case, but it's usually a dangerous idea to tie your classes with `window.onload` like that, as it will only trigger once. You can usually achieve the same effect in a more organized way just adding one function to onload, and calling other functions from there. But, it depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: Well when you have multiple components like an accordian with sub elements like a checkbox they can have load events. So what should I do instead of using multiple window load events, should I use DOMContentLoaded event instead? Check my updated questions code and have a look

Comment: It's not common to add that kind of event. If you created an accordion with JS, then it has been created the moment your code added it to the DOM, no need of waiting or adding that kind of events. If that accordion was in the original HTML, then you can execute all of your JS on the `window.onload`, for example. It's a common practice to add the "main"/"root" JS inside an `onload` callback as entry point, instead of writing code in the root of the JS file.

Comment: Write me an example of what you would do with the code I've written using the window load event and manipulating a property of the checkbox or accordian. I don't see any problem with how I've done it, I''ve created a load event for a checkbox to be manipulated at runtime as soon as the page loaded so I can enable or disable it on it's own load event but show me what you would do and manipulate some properties for both controls. Use my updated code.